# TouchableOpacity wont work as supposed in android

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, touchableopacity

I got an app with flatlist ,I added to the app TouchableOpacity that covers the whole screen,
works great when I click on item area but doesn't work when I click the area that got no items
this is the code of the TouchableOpacity:

```
<View style={{position: "absolute",width:'100%',height:HEIGHT,backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)',zIndex:6}}>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>setEditing(false)} style={{flex:1,zIndex:6}}>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

Its looks like the flatlist block any clicks below it also in ios its works without any problems

Answer (score 0):

Try change it to:

```
<View style={{position: "absolute",width:'100%',height:HEIGHT,backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)',zIndex:6}}>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>setEditing(false)} style={{flex:1,zIndex:7}}>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

and run it

Comment: I tried it didnt work , I fixed it by putting in the flatlist height:HEIGHT instead of flex